# How to be convinced of "modern" theories of physics as a student?

Tags: soft-question, education

I've been a student of physics in some good french university. There, I've been taught the usual physics curriculum: special relativity, quantum mechanics, statistical mechanics, classical and quantum field theory, general relativity, and all this stuff up to conformal field theory, and string theory.

As a student, I had no problem to accept that the theories I had to learn to pass my exams where actually well motivated by experiments, and were indeed explaining strange phenomenon in relevant ways.

The thing is, this acceptance is purely based on **faith**, and any physics student is actually **forced** to believe that what he is taught is not pure fiction (by lack of time, mostly).

I now find this to be a real problem: how to be convinced that a "weird" theory (such a quantum mechanics, say) is indeed necessary in order to explain subtle phenomenon (such as the wave-particle duality, say) if one isn't in the first place noticing the very existence of such phenomenon?

Don't you guys think that forcing students to learn all of this on faith is actually very bad for creativity and researches? It seems to me that coming back to these foundational experiments should be necessary for many reasons:

1) they are very good to motivate the failure of the current theories known by the student,

2) they are very good to motivate new theories,

3) they (the experiment itself and what is measured) can be reinterpreted by a student (or the forthcoming researcher) in a new and creative way that is far different from what is actually taught.

To sum-up, how to be convinced of the legitimacy and relevancy of modern physics without having to do **from scratch** the foundational experiments that motivated it in the first place? Especially when it comes to **phenomenological** theories like quantum mechanics that aren't yet well understood philosophically, and aren't motivated by abstraction and common sense only?

Comment: This sounds like a combination of an education question (which is off-topic here) and a philosophy question (which is also off-topic here).

Comment: Regarding the education part, that's probably a symptom of how French universities teach physics so abstractly. As a student at an American university, I was taught plenty about actual experiments.

Comment: taught surely, but did you build the double-slit experiements with electron from scratch? I never did it, there is always a big "faith" part you have to commit to

Comment: If you want to recreate every experiment from scratch yourself, you're going to have a lot of trouble...

Comment: Only the foundational ones, and the ones that are supposed to motivate new theories that are up to today, still not very well understood from first principles

Comment: Exactly how is the double slit experiment still not understood?

Comment: Please read what I'm saying before answering. Read, and re-read, and think

Comment: I strongly recommend the OP read the writings of Michael Polanyi, especially *Science, Faith and Society*, which deals precisely with the issue raised in the question.

Comment: You don't have to accept the theory on faith. You could, if you wanted, reproduce the experiment. And many people have done so in the past, so you're not simply trusting the word of a single experimenter. In fact, every time you listen to a compact disc, you're verifying that at least enough of QM is correct enough to turn on a laser.

Comment: @ThePhoton: you're still trusting their interpretation of what they think they do, see and measure, which is a lot when it comes to subtle things such as particles and an electron, say

Comment: @sure, you don't have to trust. They should have published a record of their actual experiment and observations, not just their interpretation. You are allowed to try to come up with a better theory yourself, if you like.

Comment: @ThePhoton: you don't understand. In order to "come up with a better theory", you first have to be convinced that there is indeed some phenomenon that is contradicting your worldview or that is too subtle and weird to be explained with satisfaction in your worldview. The only way to be convinced of the existence of such phenomenon (i.e., foundational experiments), is to redo them from scratch

Comment: We don't actually have enough time or personal energy (or for most of us *money*) for launching into a complete recapitulation of the development of modern physics including all the dead ends. (And the thing is that the dead ends rarely make it into classroom or textbook presentation, so unless you look hard you won't actually know enough to reconstruct their thinking in full.) There is just too much. But you can pick a small topics and research it in detail and show yourself that these guys checked things out. Even if you don't want to do all the experiment the library research is worthwhile.

Comment: @sure, my point is, nobody is stopping you from redoing them. Therefore you aren't taking them on faith. The people who presented them originally published their theories (not dogma) knowing that the rest of the community would be able to check their work and possibly refute or improve it.

Comment: A second important think is to look at the way the process correctes mistakes. Consider the story of N-rays. Consider the 'Oops, Leon' particle. Consider the found, retracted and re-found penta-quark. Look at the length of the debate between proponents of dark matter and modified dynamics. Look at the fact of on-going noodling around LENR (AKA cold fusion) even in the face of funding agency red-lining. And don't forget to look at the ways the correction seems to get delayed, because this is a human institution.

Comment: You do not accept a theory by faith, you either understand it or not. However, you have to have faith that the experiments were done right, usually because they were confirmed by more than one experimenter.

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is, this acceptance is purely based on faith, and any physics student is actually forced to believe that what he is taught is not pure fiction (by lack of time, mostly).

I think that you are not forced to accept is *purely* on faith.  You can check the theory makes sense yourselves and your can look for contradictory experimental evidence.  This is especially true now with the practically immediate hand-on ability to web search for almost anything.

And to be fair, no scientist can actually ever check everything themselves.

What you're really being asked to do is trust the process of peer review which is the basis of modern scientific trial-by-torture.  You're being asked to trust people with more experience and knowledge who torture test their own and other scientist's findings.

You can't really do modern science without having some trust in the process and to some extent the people.

Peer review isn't perfect, by any means, but it's pretty good.

> how to be convinced of the legitimacy and relevancy of modern physics without having to do from scratch the foundational experiments that motivated it in the first place ?

Trust the process of science.  Question the details when you understand them.

You're *supposed* to develop (in time) into a scientist who questions things.  But you have to know enough to do that properly.  Patience.

And if there's one thing doing a lab-heavy science course taught me, it's that usually the darn experiment doesn't work on the appointed day.  If we required students to learn by doing it successfully themselves it would take about 2000 years to train a typical B.Sc., which is about how long it would take you to perform all the key experiments successfully.  That's about how long it took people who I'm perfectly willing to say were better at it than me.

> Especially when it comes to phenomenological theories like quantum mechanics that aren't yet well understood philosophically, and aren't motivated by abstraction and common sense only ?

As one physicist put it, follow the mathematics.  They are theories, mathematical models intended to allow us to mathematically reproduce what nature does, apparently without the aid of a mathematics department.  They are (always in my view) approximations.  Don't look for a philosophy for the theory, just look for a theory that matches the real world.  My view is that when we find theories that match the real world within the limits we want them to, our job is done.

Anyway, Philosophy is an Arts Department thing.  We don't mess with their department, they keep their noses out of our labs.  Demarcation saves the day and eliminates the need for us to eliminate them.  Everyone wins. :-)

Comment: +1 I fully agree with all you have said, except possibly the bit about philosophers not tiptoeing into physics, they need **something** to base their conversations on. You know the line: Science tries to make difficult things simple, and Arts does the opposite.

Comment: I've deleted an inappropriate comment and its response

Answer (score 1):

You ask an excellent question which does not have easy answers.

As The Photon says, you're welcome to repeat the experiments that demonstrate these scientific theories.  Of course, as you probably noticed, it's hard to beg time on a multi-billion dollar particle accelerator just to assuage your doubts.  At some point, you are going to have to rely on the documented evidence which lead to our claiming that these theories are true.  There really isn't a way around it.

The process of doing this can be quite the hurdle.  It's very popular to teach these theories as pure truths, but the truth is we don't *know*.  We don't really *know* that electrons exist, what we know is that modeling the world as though they exist is *tremendously* effective, so much so that we see little reason to not claim that they truly exist.

Science, like so many other topics entwined in the human condition, is all about the unknown.  If I throw a ball at you at a 45 degree angle at 5m/s, you don't *actually* know where it's going to land.  There's no proof that the ball wont suddenly fly up in the sky and never return.  Its behavior is an unknown, and science teaches you a very powerful way to view your reality which suggests that you can use some sines and cosines to determine the best course of action if you want to catch the ball.  It lets you take what you know and make a best-estimate for what is going to happen in the future... and it's darn good at it.

This peering into the unknown extends to "modern" theories as well.  In principle, you could go recreate the collisions which lead us to announce the existence of the Higgs Boson.  In practice, you can't afford to do these things.  Instead, us mere mortals are taught to read experimental evidence (typically in the form of journal articles).  If we are comfortable with this layer of indirection, reading about experiments rather than doing them, we can peer over the shoulders of the teams who did the experiences.  Science teaches you the rules which they have for publishing which are designed to make this possible.

Of course, the other approach is to trust your teacher to teach you.  Sometimes this can be hard (especially with an overzelous teacher), but the relationship between student and teacher is thousands of years old, and very powerful.

Finally, one of my favorite places to look for validation of modern theories is engineering and technology.  Engineering is always pushing the limits of the profitable portion of science.  Quite often this provides beautiful validations of the science.  For example, in electronics, diodes have something called a "breakdown voltage" at which point they undergo avalanche breakdown.  The reasons for this are deep in the bowels of quantum physics involving the ever diminishing length of a depletion region in the diode.  I can't say it's "proof" of the quantum effects, but its an effect which is well explained by quantum mechanics and is not well explained by other reasons.   GPS is another great example.  GPS receivers *must* account for relativistic effects because they are measuring time so precisely and the satellites are moving so fast.

Comment: The thing is, I believe that it is precisely the act of trying to redo the **foundational** experiments trying to "prove" some worldview or to disprove it which are going to teach you that: 1) theories are just relevant worldviews and are by no mean "true" or "false" as you pointed out, 2) there is a necessity for a new worldview because some phenomenon are too subtle to be explained in your current ones 3) it is perfectly possible to disagree with modern physics and its phenomenological theories (such as QM), and you're always free to try to reinterpret what you *see* and how it was produced

Comment: +1  "knowledge is merely opinion", as stated in this Tim Minchin video, apologies if you have seen it....https://youtu.be/V0W7Jbc_Vhw

Comment: @Sure, ahh, what you describe there is quite deep in the heart of the philosophy of science.  I can definitely appreciate where you are coming from (I spend time there myself).    It does, however, get tricky.  The path of science as Popper might have described it does not pay much attention to the actual resource costs of falsification, which have gotten quite high in the worlds of particle physics and cosmology.  I think dmckee had the best suggestion for you: specialize.  Find some nook where you can keep progressing science while revisiting the foundational hypotheses that you want to see

Comment: ... with your own eyes.  As for the average student, however, I think I'm comfortable in saying that it's not worth the cost for everyone to go down that path.  Only a few who show interest, such as yourself, are really needed to keep the community honest.  I liken it to learning martial arts.  In virtually every martial arts class, you hope to *never* have to redo their foundational experiments, because the cost of testing the foundations of a martial art can be dire indeed, and paid in lives.

Answer (score 0):

> To sum-up, how to be convinced of the legitimacy and relevancy of modern physics without having to do from scratch the foundational experiments that motivated it in the first place? Especially when it comes to phenomenological theories like quantum mechanics that aren't yet well understood philosophically, and aren't motivated by abstraction and common sense only?

I am lost a bit here, if you are studying physics, which is ultimately an emperically based discipline, why should it matter in the least whether it is understood on a philosophical level? Do you really believe anyone is ever going to fully understand quantum mechanics by simply talking about it?

I fully agree with StephenG, and I think you are being unnecessarily rude to him.  If you take things on faith, well you have only yourself to blame.

How can you be **forced** to take anything on faith, are you physically restrained from performing any experiments yourself, or talking to the researchers concerned. I don't understand. Exactly **how** are you forced?